# Necesito extraer la key de un diccionario para guardarla en una variable

Tags: python, xml, lista, diccionarios

Estoy realizando un programa en el que utilizando la lista de diccionarios, necesito extraer por separado los valores "etiqueta", "atributo" y "Valor".
He conseguido obtener los valores de "etiqueta" y "valor", pero no soy capaz de extraer el valor "atributo" debido a que es una key de mi diccionario.

Os enseño la lista de diccionarios tal y como se imprime en pantalla:

```
[
  ["root-layout", { width: "248", height: "300", "background-color": "blue" }],
  ["region", { id: "a", top: "20", bottom: "", left: "64", right: "" }],
  ["region", { id: "b", top: "120", bottom: "", left: "20", right: "" }],
  [
    "region",
    { id: "text_area", top: "100", bottom: "", left: "20", right: "" }
  ],
  [
    "img",
    {
      src: "http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.jpg",
      region: "a",
      begin: "2s",
      dur: "36s"
    }
  ],
  [
    "img",
    {
      src: "http://www.content-networking.com/smil/earthrise.jpg",
      region: "b",
      begin: "12s",
      dur: ""
    }
  ],
  [
    "audio",
    {
      src: "http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.wav",
      begin: "1s",
      dur: ""
    }
  ],
  ["textstream", { src: "http://gsyc.es/~grex/letra.rt", region: "text_area" }],
  ["audio", { src: "cancion.ogg", begin: "4s", dur: "" }]
];
```

---

```
import sys
from xml.sax import make_parser
from smallsmilhandler import SmallSMILHandler


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:

        file = sys.argv[1]
        parser = make_parser()
        cHandler = SmallSMILHandler()
        parser.setContentHandler(cHandler)
        parser.parse(open(file))
        listavalores = cHandler.get_tags()

        for linea in listavalores:
            lista_final = []
            etiqueta = linea[0]
            dic_atributo = linea [1].keys()
            atributo = dic_atributo
            valor = linea[1]['width']

            print(etiqueta)
            print(atributo)
            print(valor)


    except IndexError:

        sys.exit("Usage:python3 karaoke.py file.smil")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No está muy claro lo que preguntas. ¿Quieres obtener una lista de todas las etiquetas (que son el primer elemento de tus listas) más todos los atributos y sus correspondientes valores que hay en el diccionario asociado a la etiqueta?

Si entendí correctamente, esto sería lo que buscas:

```
for linea in listavalores:
    lista_final = []
    etiqueta = linea[0]
    for atributo, valor in linea[1].items():
      print(etiqueta, atributo, valor)
```

Para la lista que muestras en la pregunta, lo que imprimiría este código sería:

```
root-layout width 248
root-layout height 300
root-layout background-color blue
region id a
region top 20
region bottom 
region left 64
region right 
region id b
region top 120
region bottom 
region left 20
region right 
region id text_area
region top 100
region bottom 
region left 20
region right 
img src http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.jpg
img region a
img begin 2s
img dur 36s
img src http://www.content-networking.com/smil/earthrise.jpg
img region b
img begin 12s
img dur 
audio src http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.wav
audio begin 1s
audio dur 
textstream src http://gsyc.es/~grex/letra.rt
textstream region text_area
audio src cancion.ogg
audio begin 4s
audio dur
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreto que la estructura de tu lista de dictionarios es la siguiente:

*[[listaString1, {key1:value1, key2:value2, ...}],
 [listaString2, {key3:value3, key4:value4, ...}]]*

cuando estas iterando en el loop supongo que:
etiqueta = listaString1
atributo = key1
valor = value1

El punto clave esta en el loop, 
donde obtienes todas las llaves(atributos) del diccionario. 
Asi que como ejemplo pondre otro diccionario parecido al tuyo

```
print("creating list of list of dicts")

myDict1 = {"width":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"};
myDict2 = {"nowidth":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"};
myDict3 = {"nowidth":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"};


list1 = ["etiqueta1",myDict1];
list2 = ["etiqueta2",myDict2];
list3 = ["etiqueta3",myDict3];

upperList = [list1, list2, list3]

print(upperList)

for linea in upperList:
    #lista_final = []
    etiqueta = linea[0]#lees el primer elemento de la lista, que es otra lista
    dic_atributo = linea [1].keys(); #lees el segundo elemento de la lista, que es un diccionario y extraes todas las llaves.
    print(type(dic_atributo))
    print(dic_atributo)
    atributo = list(dic_atributo)[0] #aqui todas las llaves del diccionario en forma de lista<--- pero que llave quieres extraer, la primera? pues por eso añadimos un [0], que es width. 
    print(type(linea[1]))
    try:
        valor = (linea[1])['width']; #aqui seleccionas el valor de la llave width
    except:
        valor = None;
        print ("============\n!!!Este diccionario no contiene la llave 'width'\n Asi que solo obtendremos: etiqueta y atributo y el valor vacio 'none'\n==============");
    print(etiqueta);
    print(atributo);
    print(valor);
```

Espero que ahora entiendas como obtienes los datos y como seleccionar de la **lista** 'dic_atributo' el valor [0] (o el que desees).